# XSL to transform XML to Excel xls sheet

Tags: xml, excel, xslt, xls

I'm having trouble creating an Excel file from an XSL transform. Most questions and tutorials I have found are from 7 or more years ago when Excel 2003 was still quite common, so I'm not sure if it's possible for Excel 2010 or later.

This is my transform, the cells will have data from an XML dataset, but for now I'd just like to be able to open the output file correctly in excel, which I can't do.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
xmlns:user="urn:my-scripts" 
xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" 
xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" 
xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">

        <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
        <xsl:template match="/">
            <xsl:processing-instruction name="mso-application">progid="Excel.Sheet"</xsl:processing-instruction>
            <Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" 
            xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" 
            xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" 
            xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" 
            xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
                <Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet1">
                    <Table x:FullColumns="1" x:FullRows="1" ss:DefaultRowHeight="15">
                        <Row>
                            <Cell>
                                <Data ss:Type="String">a</Data>
                            </Cell>
                            <Cell>
                                <Data ss:Type="String">b</Data>
                            </Cell>
                        </Row>
                        <Row>
                            <Cell>
                                <Data ss:Type="String">c</Data>
                            </Cell>
                            <Cell>
                                <Data ss:Type="String">d</Data>
                            </Cell>
                        </Row>
                    </Table>
                </Worksheet>
            </Workbook>
        </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If I save the transformed file as XML I get the following output, which is similar to what I get if I save an Excel sheet as "XML Spreadsheet 2003".

```
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
    <Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" 
    xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" 
    xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" 
    xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" 
    xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
      <Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet1">
    <Table x:FullColumns="1" x:FullRows="1" ss:DefaultRowHeight="15">
      <Row>
        <Cell>
          <Data ss:Type="String">a</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell>
          <Data ss:Type="String">b</Data>
        </Cell>
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Cell>
          <Data ss:Type="String">c</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell>
          <Data ss:Type="String">d</Data>
        </Cell>
      </Row>
    </Table>
  </Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

However if I save the output as ".xls", and open it in Excel it looks like this:
[image: xls output file showing blank sheet with data in one cell]

I've tried saving an Excel file as "XML Spreadsheet 2003", and opening it in Excel again it opens correctly, however when I copy the XML into the stylesheet and transform, the resulting xsl file opens as above.

I'm using a python script to do the transform, which is working fine for other transforms, so I don't know what the issue is with the stylesheet.

EDIT:

I'm using Excel 2010. This is the error I'm getting before Excel opens the xls file, once I click OK, I get the above view.
[image: xml to xls file]

This is what I get if I give the transformed file the "xlsx" extension, if I click ok, nothing opens. 
[image: xml to xlsx file]

I get the same result if I open via the File -> Open route, except the xlsx file either shows the error, or opens a blank Excel instance.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to open your transformed XML in **MS Office 2016** (*File->Open file*) and in **Libre Office 5** (*Insert->Sheet From File*), so it was opened as **A1**="a", **B1**="b", **A2**="c" and **B2**="d".

Also try to rename extension of transformed XML file as "xlsx" (MS Excel 2007-2013) and after open you will have result as below:

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help, I've tried naming it "xlsx" but I still get the same issue. I've added an Edit to the question with the errors I get when I open the file in Excel.